Build a Tx Rx USB LED indicator
I want to make a indicator LED light which would blink when there is data flow from the computer to the storage drive.
I have checked using a multimeter that whenever data flows there is a voltage of 1V in the TX/Rx lines of the USB port.
So, can I create a circuit using NPN transistor or any MOSFET to make a LED glow when there is a data flow?
I have seen such a light in pen drives and portable hard drives.

there is data flow at all times ... just wire the LED to the USB power pins

Yes, but you may not be pleased with the result.
The good news, if there is voltage, you could parallel a circuit off the signal to light up an LED.
The bad news, as @jsotola observed, data flows (or can flow) all the time, when it says BUS that means it is (or can be) shared with other stuff.
Another point, if you are transferring data, the signal will be fast which means timing is critical.  If you put a circuit off to the side, you may interfere with that and you'll get flashing lights and no data transfer.
That sounds like a good science fiction project. ("Fiction" because nobody would believe anybody would actually do something like that.)  I think I would start with a mouse or keyboard, those are super-slow USB 1.0 devices that are not quite so timing critical. If you get that going, you could use it with a USB 2.0 flash drive and see if you get an impact on data transfer.
As I said, it sounds like an interesting project that will take a few hours and may or may not produce anything useful but you'll have fun working on it in the meantime.  Good luck.

I was talking about this light. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odw-TqbCfqCP_JEQI6smA7dSSWmZ1QNp/
